# Get week of year - expressions and functions in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I'm pretty new to ADF and I'm trying to parametrise a variable that takes as input year and week of the year; for example, 202042 or 202102

After digging a bit, I created the below function, but it looks like weekOfYear is not available.

what is the way to get weekOfYear in ADF?

```
@concat('PREFIX',
formatdatetime(utcnow(), 'yyyy'),
weekOfYear((formatdatetime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMdd'))),
‘.SUFFIX’)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to look it up in your date warehouse date dimension which should have this column.  If not, speak to your data architect.

If you do need to calculate it, then if you have some SQL compute you could use a Lookup activity and the SQL like this:

`sp_executesql N'select datepart(week,getdate()) weekOfYear'`

This returned the following result:

```
Output
{
    "firstRow": {
        "weekOfYear": 6
    },
...
```

[image: Pipeline]

A Microsoft SQL database (whether it be IaaS / box product, Azure SQL DB, Managed Instance or Azure Synapse Analytics) also supports ISO week as part of the `DATEPART` function, so you could do this:

```
sp_executesql N'SELECT DATEPART( iso_week, GETDATE() ) isoWeekNum'
```

This is also possible within core ADF (not Mapping Data Flows) using the built-in functions.  ADF does support date functions `dayOfYear` and `dayOfWeek` and *Week of Year* is really just maths with these two variables according to the Wikipedia article:

[image: Wikipedia article on ISOWeek date]

This calculation implemented in ADF as an expression is like this:

```
@string(div(sub(add(10, dayOfYear(utcNow())), dayOfWeek(utcNow())),7))
```

**NB** This is **not** ISO week but *Week in Year* and that the ADF `dayOfWeek` function starts with Sunday as 0 as per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#dayOfWeek).  I'm converting it to a string here in order to assign it to a variable in ADF but it will depend on where you use the expression.

Mapping Data Flows does also support the function [weekOfYear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expression-functions#weekofyear) so consider that if you are already using Mapping Data Flows.

Comment: Could you please give an example of how to do it using built-in adf functions

Comment: Yes can do, can you confirm what your week of year calculation is?  ie is the same as the SQL Server implementation above or is it ISO week for example?

Comment: It's the ISO week

Comment: I've updated the post with some more examples, see how you get on.  ISOWeek is available in SQL so this is still the easiest way, but I've also added an example of calculating this type of thing using built-in ADF functions to get 'Week of Year' (not ISOweek).

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible directly, you will have to use mapping data flows.

You can get more information from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/118057/is-there-an-azure-data-factory-function-to-get-the.html) link

Comment: Fire up a whole Apache Spark cluster to calculate week of year?  I wouldn't.  The additional cost and complexity (ie additional components to maintain) are not worth it.  Simply look this up in your warehouse date dimension.

Comment: You don't fire up a Spark cluster and you don't maintain it. ADF provides the serverless compute for you. Calculating fields in data flows is absolutely the right place to do this in ADF.

Comment: Correct ! and that is the reason why I recommended it